# generic solution for Rewriteurl for all URL's

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having an issue with incoming URLs. I'm trying to remove trailing slash in every incoming request URL

I Searched and studied other posts and made consolidated rules for individual URL's in htaccess as follows

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +MultiViews

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+WCOM/Flatsome/product-category/women/[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /WCOM/Flatsome/product-category/women [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+WCOM/Flatsome/feed/[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /WCOM/Flatsome/feed [L,R=301]
```

They are working fine, but for individual URL / Directory / sub Directory , I am looking for a generic solution which can accept any incoming request and *remove* slash in last segment.

Many post here are providing solution for specific URL ...
Is there any generic way to do this?

Also, the following solution:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

is not pointing out right URL .. For example

```
http://localhost/WCOM//Flatsome/pages/about-us/
```

is pointing to
     http://localhost/about-us

### Question

How can I rectify this URL issue?

Comment: i didnt understand by lock down .. I just want to remove trailing slash from the very last Page (like from feed in /WCOM/Flatsome/feed) .. My evry Href links have slash in it

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: My issue is not solved , I am havng issues in URL , I have edited the Post

Comment: should work. Maybe some other rule is interfering. You can test your rewrite rules here: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/